# how to add two unioned queries together

Tags: sqlite, group-by, aggregate

I'm trying to add the two group by al together, this is my code:

```
SELECT VISITOR,COUNT(VISITOR)
FROM ENGLAND
WHERE TIER = 1 AND SEASON >= 1980
GROUP BY VISITOR
UNION
SELECT HOME,COUNT(HOME)
FROM ENGLAND
WHERE TIER = 1 AND SEASON >= 1980
GROUP BY HOME;
```

here is a part of the output

```
AFC Bournemouth 37
AFC Bournemouth 38
```

and the question is how am I able to make the output looks like

```
AFC Bournemouth 75
```

(which means add the home and visitor num of games together)

Comment: You should improve the question, add formatting etc

Comment: by formatting, you mean....?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection.
>   — David Wheeler

You want to add values for the same name together? Just use SUM() and GROUP BY:

```
SELECT Name, SUM(Games) AS Games
FROM (SELECT Visitor AS Name, COUNT(*) AS Games
      FROM England
      WHERE Tier = 1 AND Season >= 1980
      GROUP BY Visitor
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Home, COUNT(*)
      FROM England
      WHERE Tier = 1 AND Season >= 1980
      GROUP BY Home)
GROUP BY Name;
```

(UNION without ALL would remove duplicates, which could happen if there are the same number of home and visitor games.)

---

Alternatively, bring the values of the original table in a form that allows them all to be aggregated at once:

```
SELECT Name, COUNT(*) AS Games
FROM (SELECT Visitor AS Name
      FROM England
      WHERE Tier >= 1 AND Season >= 1980
      UNION ALL
      SELECT Home
      FROM England
      WHERE Tier >= 1 AND Season >= 1980)
GROUP BY Name;
```